# Strip url with multiple values in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a url of this form

```
http://localhost:8100/my-child/2
```

When when i click a button i am getting result as

```
http://localhost:8100/my-child/2/5
```

How to adjust the url to fit to this form as

```
http://localhost:8100/my-child/5
```

This is my code snippet

```
  this.href = this.router.url;
   console.log(this.router.url);
   this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url+id);
```

Can you please tell me how to adjust the code to get the required output.

Comment: Assuming that `2` and `5` are both ids of `my-child`, you must have you route defined for when you enter `my-child/2`. Use the same route, pass different param

Comment: thaks Juilius. I shall try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use route params:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' }
  { path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductDetails }
];
```

Code to navigate to the route:

```
goToProductDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/product-details', id]);
}
```